# EFK Kubernetes Log Aggregation

Tags: kubernetes, efk

I am installing EFK stack to 100 days old cluster. Fluentd will pick up the logs of 100 days and will start sending to Elastic.
Is there a provision that fluentd starts aggregating the log from today and not from beginning life cycle of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [Fluentd documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#limit_recently_modified), you can find `limit_recently_modified` flag, which allows limit the watching files that the modification time is within the specified time range.

Here's how the `limit_recently_modified` can be used in conf file:

```
...
<source>
    exclude_path ["/var/log/wedge/*/*/MattDaemon*.log"]
    path_key source
    format none
    read_from_head true
    tag foo.*
    path /var/log/wedge/*/*/*.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/wedgelog
    limit_recently_modified 86400s
    @type tail
</source>
...
```

Another option is to use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-ignore-older) (instead of Fluentd), where you can find `ignore_older` flag. Filebeat ignores any files that were modified before the specified timespan.

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but in the YAML can we set this as an environment variable or is there another way?

Comment: @Arpan Sharma I have edited answer and added conf file. `limit_recently_modified` parameter is useful when use * in the path. If target files are not updated within `limit_recently_modified`, such files are ignored from watching list.